# Pass information to another view with NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, navigationlink

I have following View and I need to pass `item` content to another View (DetailsEvent.swift), I am using `NavigationLink` . (I'm using Xcode 11 GM)

```
struct Events: View {

    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

            List(self.networkManager.eventos.events){ item in

                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsEvent(item: item))  {

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                      HStack {

                        Image(systemName: "calendar")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)

                        Text(item.start_date)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                      }

                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.headline)                    
                }
              }

           }
            .navigationBarTitle("Events")
        }
    }
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Without passing any variable: `NavigationLink (destination: DetailsEvent ()` everything works fine.

DetailsEvent.swift

```
struct DetailsEvent: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("here details content")
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: added information (at the moment it is an empty view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your struct has no property called item. You need something like this:

```
struct DetailsEvent: View {

    let item: Event

    var body: some View {
        Text("here details about \(item.title)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Declaring the variable in the destination  view now works correctly for me.