# macOS - Error while passing information through UI View

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-view

I am trying to pass information from one SwiftUI View (let's say `View1`) to another one (`View2`) using `NavigationLink`. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896764/pass-information-to-another-view-with-navigationlink) article, but when I try to run it I get the error `"Cannot find type 'Event'  in scope"`:
[image: annot find type 'Event' in scope]

Here is my code for `View1`:

```swift
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
struct Mods_UI: View {
    let PassMe = "Hello!"
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: MarkdownView(item: String(PassMe))) {
                Label("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for `View2`:

```swift
struct MarkdownView: View {
    let item: Event
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(item))
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong. If more information is needed, please tell me.

Swift Version: Latest (5.3.3)

Xcode Version: Latest (12.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you linked to, they have a custom type called `Event`, probably defined as a `struct` somewhere in their code that was not included in the post.

You, however are just trying to pass a `String` around. You can do this:

```
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
struct Mods_UI: View {
    let passMe = "Hello!"
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: MarkdownView(item: passMe)) {
                Label("Hello World!")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MarkdownView: View {
    var item: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! This makes a lot of sense, but when I am running the script I get the error `Missing argument for parameter 'item' in call` at the bottom of `View2` (PreviewProvider). I just tried using `item: item`, and `item: String`, but they also return errors. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You aren't showing the `PreviewProvider` code, which would be helpful to give you an exact answer, but that error is telling you that you need to include an `item` parameter, which is a String. You probably want `item: "Test"` or something like that -- "Test" can be whatever you want the default value to be for the preview display.